# How to decrypt a Windows 10 partition in Ubuntu

Tags: command-line, permissions, 17.04, desktop-environments

I encrypt my partition of 496GB (NTFS) in window 10  with bitlocker (TPM enabled motherboard). Now i switches to Ubuntu 17.04 
But i forget to remove the decryption of that partition
Is it possible to decrypt that partition (sda2) in Ubuntu ?, although i know passwd 
i would really appreciate this, if someone could help
i tried With dislocker but showing false error **cannot parse volume header.Abort**

Comment: How exactly was the partition encrypted? Did you use a third-party software or any Windows feature?

Comment: i did through bit-locker (no 3rd party software),, this is tpm enabled motherboard

Comment: Please *always* add additional information directly to your question ([edit]) rather than in comments.